# Add a class to a figure only if a image within figure has a class

Tags: jquery, if-statement

How would I add a class to a `figure` element if an image inside it has a class of `right`?, I only want this to execute if a image has a class of `right`.

```
$(function() {
if ($('img').hasClass('right')) {
  $('figure').addClass('test');
 }
 });
```

This adds a class `test` to every `figure` on the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
$('img.right').closest('figure').addClass('test');
```

If the `figure` element is always the immediate parent element you could also use:

```
$('img.right').parent('figure').addClass('test');
```

---

As a side note, the reason your example wasn't working was because you were adding the class `test` to ***all*** figure elements when you used `$('figure').addClass('test')`.

You needed to get the context of the element, which would look more like this:

```
$('img.right').each(function(){
    $(this).parent('figure').addClass('test');
});
```

Avoid the `.each()` loop and use one of the other suggestions, though.

Comment: Wow. Thanks Josh (and Kobi)! That must be a record. Super fast. I went with .parent

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation! Much appreciated.

Comment: In the `each()` example, why not use `$(this.parentNode).addClass(...)` and avoid the unnecessary call to `parent(...)`?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Yep, that would work, but it also assumes the parent element is *always* a `figure` element. It *may* not be. The entire `each()` loop is unnecessary, though. Hence "Avoid the .each() loop and use one of the other suggestions". I just meant for that to be a formal explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector:

```
$('figure:has(img.right)').addClass('test');
```